# How to format date value before setting to a date picker input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datebox

Using JQuery, I created a simple date text field with `dateFormat: "mmddyy"`. There is no problem in the way it works. But the corresponding database field is of type DATE and stores the value in "YYYY-MM-DD" format. So, when I read the value from database and set it to the date text field, the date format appears to be "YYYY-MM-DD", but not "mmddyy". So, how can we format that database date value in JQuery before setting it to the date field ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you select it from the DB in the correct format? Depending on which db you are using you can usually do it with a simple convert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try Jquery Date format plugin to accomplish it.

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat

Comment: You could also use http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format. I personally prefer this one compared to jQuery Plugin

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery UI, check out this page [jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altFormat](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-altFormat)

Answer (score 0):

put this code to your `datebox`

```
data-options="formatter:myformatter"
```

and add the function like below

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function myformatter(date){
       var y = date.getYear();
       var m = date.getMonth()+1;
       var d = date.getDate();
       return (m<10?('0'+m):m)+(d<10?('0'+d):d)+y;
    }

 </script>
```